# Swagger - timestamp weird representation

Tags: spring-boot, swagger

I have Spring Boot controller and for easy API reference used Swagger. 
Question about `timestamp`. Why in generated documentation example looks like:

`"timestamp": {
      "date": 0,
      "day": 0,
      "hours": 0,
      "minutes": 0,
      "month": 0,
      "nanos": 0,
      "seconds": 0,
      "time": 0,
      "timezoneOffset": 0,
      "year": 0
    }`

So why swagger have so strange example for timestamp no just simple numeric value, which standard describes this representation?

Comment: Related: [Change model schema for java.sql.Time in swagger-ui](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33264127/change-model-schema-for-java-sql-time-in-swagger-ui)

Answer (score 8):

check open specification of Swagger (https://github.com/OAI/OpenAPI-Specification/blob/master/versions/2.0.md).

If you want to solve the issue, try this sample spring boot application

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.sql.Timestamp;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;
import springfox.documentation.builders.PathSelectors;
import springfox.documentation.builders.RequestHandlerSelectors;
import springfox.documentation.service.ApiInfo;
import springfox.documentation.spi.DocumentationType;
import springfox.documentation.spring.web.plugins.Docket;
import springfox.documentation.swagger2.annotations.EnableSwagger2;

@SpringBootApplication
@RestController
@EnableSwagger2
public class DemoApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(DemoApplication.class, args);
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/api", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public Demo messages(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException {
        java.util.Date date = new java.util.Date();
        return new Demo(new Timestamp(date.getTime()));
    }

    @Bean
    public Docket docket() {
        return new Docket(DocumentationType.SWAGGER_2).select()
                .apis(RequestHandlerSelectors.basePackage(getClass().getPackage().getName())).paths(PathSelectors.any())
                .build().apiInfo(generateApiInfo()).directModelSubstitute(Timestamp.class, Long.class);
    }

    private ApiInfo generateApiInfo() {
        return new ApiInfo("demo", "demo.", "Version 1.0", "urn:tos", "test", "Apache 2.0",
                "http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0");
    }
}
```

Demo Object

```
import java.sql.Timestamp;

public class Demo {
private Timestamp time;

public Timestamp getTime() {
    return time;
}

public void setTime(Timestamp time) {
    this.time = time;
}

public Demo(Timestamp time) {
    super();
    this.time = time;
}

public Demo() {
    super();
}
```

}

check below image or open http://localhost:8080/swagger-ui.html

[image]

`.directModelSubstitute(Timestamp.class, Long.class)` is responsible of mapping between timestamp type and numeric type