# In my Swagger2 documentation of Spring Boot I get Timestamp fields documentation as a JSON object

Tags: spring-boot, swagger-2.0, springfox

I have a fields as createdDT as java.sql.Timestamp type which is shown as below in my swagger documentation. Can anyone help me to have this field in the format as yyyy-mm-dd or the format can be customized.

I am using springfox-swagger-ui 2.8.0 and springfox-swagger2 2.8.0.

Thanks in advance.

```
createdDt": {
            "date": 0,
            "day": 0,
            "hours": 0,
            "minutes": 0,
            "month": 0,
            "nanos": 0,
            "seconds": 0,
            "time": 0,
            "timezoneOffset": 0,
            "year": 0
          },
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, please use `directModelSubstitute(Timestamp.class, Long.class)` so that Timestamp appears as Long in the Swagger documentation. See this complete answer: [Swagger - timestamp weird representation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46118593/swagger-timestamp-weird-representation)

Comment: Thanks I tried it and it is working but I have also used

    `@ApiModelProperty(required = true,example = "2016-01-01")
 @Column(name = "createdDt")
 public Timestamp createdDt;`
So now in doc I get "2016-01-01" and for other date filed it comes as 0.

So my question is what if I want to use string format in doc as yyyy-mm-dd then in

directModelSubstitute function what should be passed.

Thanks

Comment: Well, that example specifies a date, but timestamp contains also hour, minute, second, ..nanosecond! So, your example would be wrong. Depending on how you configure Spring, a valid example would be "2019-01-01T22:33:04Z" or a long.  Now, for the specific question: I didn't try this, but you could also try with directModelSubstitute(Timestamp.class, String.class).

Comment: Thanks Vlad for your help. I will try with this also.

Answer (score 0):

```
@ApiModelProperty(value = "description", name = "notificationExpiryDate",
            dataType = "String", example = "2022-01-16T08:42:37.484Z")
private Timestamp expiryDate;
```

Giving the dataType as String made me get the example as it is in swagger page for the URLs.